# get file size created with file_put_contents

Tags: php

I am uploading files with **file_put_contents**. Is there any way i can calculate file size like we do with *move_uploaded_file* ? I believe string length and file_size are two dufferent things.

Comment: A string is just a sequence of bytes of a defined length. Therefore, if you read all of a file's contents into a string, then it's strlen should return the number of bytes of that file...

Comment: Call `file_size` with `file_put_content` 's `$filename` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs relating to [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) return value:

> The function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
$filesize = file_put_contents($myFile, $someData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `filesize()` that calculates the size of a file. You pass the filepath as a parameter:

```
$filesize = filesize("myfiles/file.txt");
```

You could then use a function like this to format the filesize to make it more user friendly:

```
function format_bytes($a_bytes) {
    if ($a_bytes < 1024) {
        return $a_bytes .' B';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1048576) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1024, 2) .' KB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1073741824) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1099511627776) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1125899906842624) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1099511627776, 2) .' TB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1152921504606846976) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1125899906842624, 2) .' PB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1180591620717411303424) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1152921504606846976, 2) .' EB';
    } elseif ($a_bytes < 1208925819614629174706176) {
        return round($a_bytes / 1180591620717411303424, 2) .' ZB';
    } else {
        return round($a_bytes / 1208925819614629174706176, 2) .' YB';
    }
}
```